# Slow performance of javascript in dynamic display:none by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I am using a script that reads the URL of the current page, checks if a specific string is present and then creates a cookie with expiration of one day. If cookie is present then I set display = none to four divs by id.
The code is below and it is working. The problem is that it seems rather slow, in the way that I manage to see the div's for a little while before they dissapear.

I have tried both jquery for "hiding" the divs but also the "document.getElementById .style.display = 'none';"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvariab1= window.location.href;
if( myvariab1.indexOf('thetextiamsearhing') >= 0){
var date = new Date;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
var mexpire = "; expires="+date;
final_cookie = "mycookie =" + myvariab1+mexpire +"; path=/";
document.cookie = final_cookie;
}
 if (document.cookie.indexOf('mycookie') > -1 ) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myid1').hide();
$('#myid2').hide();
$('#myid3').hide();
$('#myid4').hide();
});
}

</script>
```

What can i do to make it faster?
The script is placed right before `</head>` closes.
The script is inside an ecommerce script, that uses jquery.

Comment: Why not server side? It's faster than everything! You can do this easily with any server side code.

Comment: Do you mean using php? I cannot attach php code to those divs (such as echo ....), so how can I hide them only by id selector, server side?

Comment: Yes, with `php` you can define a class for hiding `div` for example `.hide` then if your php return true, echo `class` else not. You can do it with simple inline `php`. But I have no idea why you can not use `php`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for the document to be completely parsed to hide the elements in question, create or append to a `style` tag to keep the elements from ever being displayed in the first place. For example:

```
var myvariab1= window.location.href;
if( myvariab1.indexOf('thetextiamsearhing') >= 0){
  var date = new Date;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  var mexpire = "; expires="+date;
  final_cookie = "mycookie =" + myvariab1+mexpire +"; path=/";
  document.cookie = final_cookie;
}
if (document.cookie.indexOf('mycookie') > -1 ) {
  document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'))
    .textContent = `
      #myid1, #myid2, #myid3, #myid4 {
        display: none;
      }
    `;
}
```

With this, there's also no need to include a heavyweight library like jQuery, which can speed up page load speed a little bit.

Of course, if a `style` tag already exists in the document, you can add rules to it instead of creating a new one, if you wish.

Comment: thnx for the answer and effort, I already have styles to each div in question. Can you elaborate more on the "you can add rules to it instead of creating a new one" ?.  Jquery is already loaded and cannot be avoided.

Comment: Even if you already have styles for each div, you can still add another rule with `display: none` as in the snippet. You can add to an existing stylesheet with, for example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. I havent, thought it that way.. Thnx, I will give it a try and post the results...

Comment: unfortunately the code you mentioned does not work for me..     I tried also  alternatives such as:              
`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(document.createElement('style'));`      or via jquery   
      `$("head").append`     I also tried moving the javascript just before          `</body>` but it doesnt work either. I also tried `append` to set last  before  `</body>` with no luck. I can see the style inside the DOM but it has no effect.

Comment: If something else is overwriting their `display` property then you'll have to get the `display: none;` to have higher priority somehow, such as with `!important`. Examine the elements to be hidden to see what styles are being applied to it, which will tell you what the other interfering style is from

Comment: I tried all priorities, the ecommerce script has so many mods that affect controllers and template/css that is impossible to know what overwrites what. The problem is that even though the css rules are present in the dom, the ids in question are dynamically created into the `<body>` from the ecommerce script later than my css rules. Even when I managed to append the `<style type="text/css">` last in the `<body>` I was able to see in the dom the appended style `#myid1 {display: none;}` and some lines before the `id="myid1"` present! I even tried `window.onload` with no success

Comment: You just have to Inspect the element to see what CSS rule is overriding the `display: none;`. Whether the elements in question are created dynamically or not makes no difference at all from a CSS perspective. Like I said, try `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the elements at the beginning using CSS and then evaluate the cookie's existence in order to show the elements or keep them hide.